# How do I extend an image across the width of a browser window with 'absolute' position?

Tags: html

Alright, so I'm trying to figure out why I can't get the 'blue' background on top to extend across the width of the page (not height)  while keeping the positioning 'absolute' ?  Here is my page and css:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20517056/jimedit2.html
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20517056/jimedit2.css

As you can see, I have the width at 100% but it won't extend.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Spend a second on Google looking for "CSS background" and you will find a ton of tutorials that will get you on the right path with how to create, set and repeat a background image. Good luck.

Comment: Please provide a simplified jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have placed the div you want to extend within the div of id jimedit2. This div has a set width of 1024px, and therefore your div extends to this width (the width of its *parent*). To fix this remove it from its parent div.

Comment: It's not only that, the background image is itself a single image that goes 1024px wide and there is no repeat applied in the CSS either.

Comment: No problems mate... Firebug, Chrome developer tools, etc. make life a little easier when debugging this stuff.

Comment: Ok, I fixed that, but the site now isn't centered - here is a pic:

http://gyazo.com/140d882bfe0b594fea1f54079841f303

I think the white menu now is just moved to the left.  Any reason why this is?

Comment: @jtm22, show us your code, the background image issue looks fixed per your code so maybe another question fresh with a jsfiddle will be in order?

Comment: Thanks - here's the code: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20517056/jimedit2.html
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20517056/jimedit2.css

The white menu isn't centered, that's the problem =(

Comment: What are you saying?  I did what you said, removed it from the parent div and this is the updated code - it doesn't fix the issue.  Stop being condescending, and I'm grateful for the help

Comment: When someone asks for code they do not merely mean giving them an webpage. Please look at some other answers. A jsFiddle is typical

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7NuPs/ - Am I supposed to have the images show up too, or is this sufficient?

Comment: Thank you - any idea how I would center the white menu box, as well as the top bar (the number doesn't seem to be lined up)?

Comment: Firstly, why are you using all images? You should be using HTML

Comment: Images as in?  You mean for the text?

Comment: For everything. See my new answer

Comment: You can position all of your images absolute

Answer (score 0):

div "jimedit2" is of fixed i.e. 1024px
and div "lightblue" is inside it. so it will only display image in width of 1024px

try to take it out of div jimedit2.

i.e.

```
    <div id="lightblue"></div>
<div id="jimedit2">
<div id="layer1"></div>
<div id="id32andersonaquinollp"></div>
<div id="i6177233600"></div>
<div id="counselorsatlaw"></div>
<div id="whitemenu"></div>
<div id="dividercopy4"></div>
<div id="dividercopy3"></div>
<div id="dividercopy5"></div>
<div id="divider"></div>
<div id="home"></div>
<div id="aboutthefirm"></div>
<div id="ourattorneys"></div>
<div id="contactus"></div>
<div id="i20112012andersonaquinollp"></div>
</div>
```

your problem will be solved.

Comment: Ok, I fixed that, but the site now isn't centered - here is a pic: gyazo.com/140d882bfe0b594fea1f54079841f303 Is there any way to get the white menu centered still and we have a deal?

Comment: replace the code inside body tag with above code.. and dont use division for menu, use list tags insted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start to what you are looking for. You can probably work out the rest yourself:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {margin: 0; padding: 0}
#blueBackground {
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-image: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20517056/jimedit2media/lightblue.gif);
    height: 121px
}
#wrapper {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    background-color: red;
    top: -121;
    position: relative;
    height: 1000px;
}
</style>

<div id="blueBackground"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
        Put your central content in here
</div>
```

Comment: The main problem is still the bluebackGround not being width = 100% of browser window.  I tried adding width:100%; and it did nothing, any reason?  Other than that, just clearing up a few things so I can get this finished - I'm not too well versed in converting this to HTML, especially the text which I modified heavily in Photoshop - can this and the white menu be added via Photoshop images?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, using absolute positioning. But I don't advise it. See this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UtSkQ/1/

Comment: Alright!  What would be the best way to add in the white menu box I created (with images as the divider and so on)?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm going no further. I'm here to help not write your code. If your really stuck, hire a web developer, or do some more research.